I'm new to Lua and creating meta files for config servers, but does anybody know why my suppressor and barrel doesn't render in game?
I'm trying to create a custom meta for a reskinned carbine rifle and to do that, I'm trying to create the necessary custom meta files for the gun and as of right now the gun is able to be spawned and it renders fine, but the only thing it doesn't render is the barrel and the suppressor. Below I have attached the metas.
weapons.meta
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 8"?>

<CWeaponInfoBlob>
    <SlotNavigateOrder>
        <Item>
            <WeaponSlots>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="420"/>
                    <Entry>SLOT_WEAPON_TREESHARIFLE</Entry>
                </Item>
            </WeaponSlots>
        </Item>
    </SlotNavigateOrder>
    <Infos>
        <Item>
            <Infos>
                <Item type="CWeaponInfo">
                    <Name>WEAPON_TREESHARIFLE</Name>
                    <Model>w_ar_treesharifle</Model>
                    <Audio>AUDIO_ITEM_CARBINERIFLE</Audio>
                    <Slot>SLOT_WEAPON_TREESHARIFLE</Slot>
                    <DamageType>BULLET</DamageType>
                    <Explosion>
                        <Default>DONTCARE</Default>
                        <HitCar>DONTCARE</HitCar>
                        <HitTruck>DONTCARE</HitTruck>
                        <HitBike>DONTCARE</HitBike>
                        <HitBoat>DONTCARE</HitBoat>
                        <HitPlane>DONTCARE</HitPlane>
                    </Explosion>
                    <FireType>INSTANT_HIT</FireType>
                    <WheelSlot>WHEEL_RIFLE</WheelSlot>
                    <Group>GROUP_RIFLE</Group>
                    <AmmoInfo ref="AMMO_RIFLE"/>
                    <AimingInfo ref="RIFLE_LO_BASE_STRAFE"/>
                    <ClipSize value="60"/>
                    <AccuracySpread value="3.000000"/>
                    <AccurateModeAccuracyModifier value="0.500000"/>
                    <RunAndGunAccuracyModifier value="2.000000"/>
                    <RunAndGunAccuracyMaxModifier value="1.000000"/>
                    <RecoilAccuracyMax value="0.500000"/>
                    <RecoilErrorTime value="3.000000"/>
                    <RecoilRecoveryRate value="1.000000"/>
                    <RecoilAccuracyToAllowHeadShotAI value="1000.000000"/>
                    <MinHeadShotDistanceAI value="1000.000000"/>
                    <MaxHeadShotDistanceAI value="1000.000000"/>
                    <HeadShotDamageModifierAI value="1000.000000"/>
                    <RecoilAccuracyToAllowHeadShotPlayer value="0.175000"/>
                    <MinHeadShotDistancePlayer value="5.000000"/>
                    <MaxHeadShotDistancePlayer value="40.000000"/>
                    <HeadShotDamageModifierPlayer value="18.000000"/>
                    <Damage value="32.000000"/>
                    <DamageTime value="0.000000"/>
                    <DamageTimeInVehicle value="0.000000"/>
                    <DamageTimeInVehicleHeadShot value="0.000000"/>
                    <HitLimbsDamageModifier value="0.500000"/>
                    <NetworkHitLimbsDamageModifier value="0.800000"/>
                    <LightlyArmouredDamageModifier value="0.750000"/>
                    <Force value="75.000000"/>
                    <ForceHitPed value="140.000000"/>
                    <ForceHitVehicle value="1200.000000"/>
                    <ForceHitFlyingHeli value="1250.000000"/>
                    <OverrideForces>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_HEAD</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="80.000000"/>
                            <ForceBack value="50.000000"/>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_NECK</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="60.000000"/>
                            <ForceBack value="90.000000"/>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_L_THIGH</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="40.000000"/>
                            <ForceBack value="1.000000"/>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_R_THIGH</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="40.000000"/>
                            <ForceBack value="1.000000"/>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_L_CALF</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="70.000000"/>
                            <ForceBack value="80.000000"/>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_R_CALF</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="60.000000"/>
                            <ForceBack value="100.000000"/>
                        </Item>
                    </OverrideForces>
                    <ForceMaxStrengthMult value="1.000000"/>
                    <ForceFalloffRangeStart value="0.000000"/>
                    <ForceFalloffRangeEnd value="50.000000"/>
                    <ForceFalloffMin value="1.000000"/>
                    <ProjectileForce value="0.000000"/>
                    <FragImpulse value="600.000000"/>
                    <Penetration value="0.100000"/>
                    <VerticalLaunchAdjustment value="0.000000"/>
                    <DropForwardVelocity value="0.000000"/>
                    <Speed value="2000.000000"/>
                    <BulletsInBatch value="1"/>
                    <BatchSpread value="0.000000"/>
                    <ReloadTimeMP value="-1.000000"/>
                    <ReloadTimeSP value="-1.000000"/>
                    <VehicleReloadTime value="1.000000"/>
                    <AnimReloadRate value="1.000000"/>
                    <BulletsPerAnimLoop value="1"/>
                    <TimeBetweenShots value="0.135000"/>
                    <TimeLeftBetweenShotsWhereShouldFireIsCached value="-1.000000"/>
                    <SpinUpTime value="0.000000"/>
                    <SpinTime value="0.000000"/>
                    <SpinDownTime value="0.000000"/>
                    <AlternateWaitTime value="-1.000000"/>
                    <BulletBendingNearRadius value="0.000000"/>
                    <BulletBendingFarRadius value="0.750000"/>
                    <BulletBendingZoomedRadius value="0.375000"/>
                    <FirstPersonBulletBendingNearRadius value="0.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonBulletBendingFarRadius value="0.750000"/>
                    <FirstPersonBulletBendingZoomedRadius value="0.375000"/>
                    <Fx>
                        <EffectGroup>WEAPON_EFFECT_GROUP_RIFLE_ASSAULT</EffectGroup>
                        <FlashFx>muz_assault_rifle</FlashFx>
                        <FlashFxAlt>muz_alternate_star</FlashFxAlt>
                        <FlashFxFP>muz_assault_rifle_fp</FlashFxFP>
                        <FlashFxAltFP/>
                        <MuzzleSmokeFx>muz_smoking_barrel</MuzzleSmokeFx>
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxFP>muz_smoking_barrel_fp</MuzzleSmokeFxFP>
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxMinLevel value="0.300000"/>
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxIncPerShot value="0.100000"/>
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxDecPerSec value="0.250000"/>
                        <ShellFx>eject_auto</ShellFx>
                        <ShellFxFP>eject_auto_fp</ShellFxFP>
                        <TracerFx>bullet_tracer</TracerFx>
                        <PedDamageHash>BulletLarge</PedDamageHash>
                        <TracerFxChanceSP value="0.150000"/>
                        <TracerFxChanceMP value="0.750000"/>
                        <FlashFxChanceSP value="1.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxChanceMP value="1.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxAltChance value="0.200000"/>
                        <FlashFxScale value="1.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxLightEnabled value="true"/>
                        <FlashFxLightCastsShadows value="false"/>
                        <FlashFxLightOffsetDist value="0.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxLightRGBAMin x="255.000000" y="93.000000" z="25.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxLightRGBAMax x="255.000000" y="100.000000" z="50.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxLightIntensityMinMax x="1.000000" y="2.000000"/>
                        <FlashFxLightRangeMinMax x="2.500000" y="3.500000"/>
                        <FlashFxLightFalloffMinMax x="1024.000000" y="1536.000000"/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxEnabled value="false"/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxDist value="5.000000"/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameDefault/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameSand/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameDirt/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameWater/>
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameFoliage/>
                    </Fx>
                    <InitialRumbleDuration value="90"/>
                    <InitialRumbleIntensity value="0.700000"/>
                    <InitialRumbleIntensityTrigger value="0.950000"/>
                    <RumbleDuration value="90"/>
                    <RumbleIntensity value="0.100000"/>
                    <RumbleIntensityTrigger value="0.800000"/>
                    <RumbleDamageIntensity value="1.000000"/>
                    <InitialRumbleDurationFps value="150"/>
                    <InitialRumbleIntensityFps value="1.000000"/>
                    <RumbleDurationFps value="95"/>
                    <RumbleIntensityFps value="1.000000"/>
                    <NetworkPlayerDamageModifier value="1.000000"/>
                    <NetworkPedDamageModifier value="1.000000"/>
                    <NetworkHeadShotPlayerDamageModifier value="1.700000"/>
                    <LockOnRange value="65.000000"/>
                    <WeaponRange value="420.000000"/>
                    <BulletDirectionOffsetInDegrees value="0.000000"/>
                    <AiSoundRange value="-1.000000"/>
                    <AiPotentialBlastEventRange value="-1.000000"/>
                    <DamageFallOffRangeMin value="47.500000"/>
                    <DamageFallOffRangeMax value="120.000000"/>
                    <DamageFallOffModifier value="0.300000"/>
                    <VehicleWeaponHash/>
                    <DefaultCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_AIM_CAMERA</DefaultCameraHash>
                    <CoverCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_AIM_IN_COVER_CAMERA</CoverCameraHash>
                    <CoverReadyToFireCameraHash/>
                    <RunAndGunCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_RUN_AND_GUN_CAMERA</RunAndGunCameraHash>
                    <CinematicShootingCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_CINEMATIC_SHOOTING_CAMERA</CinematicShootingCameraHash>
                    <AlternativeOrScopedCameraHash/>
                    <RunAndGunAlternativeOrScopedCameraHash/>
                    <CinematicShootingAlternativeOrScopedCameraHash/>
                    <CameraFov value="35.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeFov value="20.00000"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeAttachmentFov value="20.00000"/>
                    <FirstPersonRNGOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonRNGRotationOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonLTOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonLTRotationOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeOffset x="0.00000" y="-0.0200" z="-0.0230"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeAttachmentOffset x="0.00000" y="0.0000" z="-0.0280"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeRotationOffset x="-0.70000" y="0.0000" z="0.0000"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeAttachmentRotationOffset x="0.00000" y="0.0000" z="0.0000"/>
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonIdleOffset x="-0.07500000" y="0.000000" z="-0.05"/>
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonRNGOffset x="-0.025000" y="0.000000" z="-0.075000"/>
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonLTOffset x="0.025000" y="0.000000" z="-0.0750000"/>
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonScopeOffset x="0.075000" y="-0.050000" z="-0.060000"/>
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonWeaponBlockedOffset x="-0.1000000" y="0.000000" z="-0.100000"/>
                    <FirstPersonDofSubjectMagnificationPowerFactorNear value="1.025000"/>
                    <FirstPersonDofMaxNearInFocusDistance value="0.000000"/>
                    <FirstPersonDofMaxNearInFocusDistanceBlendLevel value="0.300000"/>
                    <ZoomFactorForAccurateMode value="1.300000"/>
                    <RecoilShakeHash>ASSAULT_RIFLE_RECOIL_SHAKE</RecoilShakeHash>
                    <RecoilShakeHashFirstPerson>FPS_ASSAULT_RIFLE_RECOIL_SHAKE</RecoilShakeHashFirstPerson>
                    <AccuracyOffsetShakeHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_ACCURACY_OFFSET_SHAKE</AccuracyOffsetShakeHash>
                    <MinTimeBetweenRecoilShakes value="100"/>
                    <RecoilShakeAmplitude value="0.333000"/>
                    <ExplosionShakeAmplitude value="-1.000000"/>
                    <ReticuleHudPosition x="0.000000" y="0.000000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMin x="0.250000" y="0.200000" z="0.600000"/>
                    <AimProbeLengthMin value="0.430000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMax x="0.165000" y="-0.180000" z="0.470000"/>
                    <AimProbeLengthMax value="0.340000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSIdle x="0.162000" y="0.225000" z="0.052000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMedFPSIdle x="0.187000" y="0.197000" z="0.321000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSIdle x="0.155000" y="0.038000" z="0.364000"/>
                    <AimOffsetEndPosMinFPSIdle x="-0.284000" y="0.612000" z="-0.205000"/>
                    <AimOffsetEndPosMedFPSIdle x="-0.178000" y="0.639000" z="0.616000"/>
                    <AimOffsetEndPosMaxFPSIdle x="-0.21700" y="-0.096000" z="0.887000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSLT x="0.180000" y="0.231000" z="0.669000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSLT x="0.048000" y="-0.225000" z="0.409000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSRNG x="0.120000" y="0.275000" z="0.509000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSRNG x="0.138000" y="-0.212000" z="0.518000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSScope x="0.090000" y="0.078000" z="0.531000"/>
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSScope x="0.006000" y="-0.059000" z="0.694000"/>
                    <TorsoAimOffset x="-1.000000" y="0.550000"/>
                    <TorsoCrouchedAimOffset x="0.100000" y="0.120000"/>
                    <LeftHandIkOffset x="0.015000" y="0.095000" z="-0.008000"/>
                    <ReticuleMinSizeStanding value="0.600000"/>
                    <ReticuleMinSizeCrouched value="0.500000"/>
                    <ReticuleScale value="0.300000"/>
                    <ReticuleStyleHash>WEAPONTYPE_RIFLE</ReticuleStyleHash>
                    <FirstPersonReticuleStyleHash/>
                    <PickupHash>PICKUP_WEAPON_TREESHARIFLE</PickupHash>
                    <MPPickupHash>PICKUP_AMMO_BULLET_MP</MPPickupHash>
                    <HumanNameHash>WEAPON_TREESHARIFLE</HumanNameHash>
                    <MovementModeConditionalIdle>MMI_2Handed</MovementModeConditionalIdle>
                    <StatName>CRBNRIFLE</StatName>
                    <KnockdownCount value="-1"/>
                    <KillshotImpulseScale value="1.000000"/>
                    <NmShotTuningSet>Automatic</NmShotTuningSet>
                    <AttachPoints>
                        <Item>
                            <AttachBone>WAPSupp</AttachBone>
                            <Components>
                                <Item>
                                    <Default value="true"/>
                                    <Name>COMPONENT_TREESHARIFLE_SUPP</Name>
                                </Item>
                            </Components>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <AttachBone>WAPClip</AttachBone>
                            <Components>
                                <Item>
                                    <Default value="true"/>
                                    <Name>COMPONENT_TREESHARIFLE_CLIP_01</Name>
                                </Item>
                                <Item>
                                    <Default value="true"/>
                                    <Name>COMPONENT_TREESHARIFLE_CLIP_02</Name>
                                </Item>
                            </Components>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <AttachBone>WAPBarrel</AttachBone>
                            <Components>
                                <Item>
                                    <Name>COMPONENT_AT_TREESHARIFLE_BARREL_01</Name>
                                    <Default value="true" />
                                </Item>
                                <Item>
                                    <Name>COMPONENT_AT_TREESHARIFLE_BARREL_02</Name>
                                    <Default value="true" />
                                </Item>
                            </Components>
                        </Item>
                    </AttachPoints>
                    <GunFeedBone/>
                    <TargetSequenceGroup/>
                    <WeaponFlags>CarriedInHand Automatic Gun CanLockonOnFoot CanLockonInVehicle CanFreeAim TwoHanded AnimReload AnimCrouchFire UsableOnFoot UsableInCover AllowEarlyExitFromFireAnimAfterBulletFired NoLeftHandIKWhenBlocked AllowCloseQuarterKills HasLowCoverReloads HasLowCoverSwaps LongWeapon UseFPSAimIK UseFPSSecondaryMotion</WeaponFlags>
                    <TintSpecValues ref="TINT_DEFAULT"/>
                    <FiringPatternAliases ref="FIRING_PATTERN_RIFLE"/>
                    <ReloadUpperBodyFixupExpressionData ref="default"/>
                    <AmmoDiminishingRate value="3"/>
                    <AimingBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <FiringBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <StealthAimingBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <StealthFiringBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <AimingLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <FiringLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <StealthAimingLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <StealthFiringLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000"/>
                    <ExpandPedCapsuleRadius value="0.000000"/>
                    <AudioCollisionHash/>
                    <HudDamage value="32"/>
                    <HudSpeed value="65"/>
                    <HudCapacity value="40"/>
                    <HudAccuracy value="55"/>
                    <HudRange value="45"/>
                </Item>
            </Infos>
        </Item>
    </Infos>
    <Name>AR</Name>
</CWeaponInfoBlob>

COMPONENT_TREESHARIFLE_SUPP/weaponcomponents.meta
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 8"?>

<CWeaponComponentInfoBlob>
    <Infos>
        <Item type="CWeaponComponentSuppressorInfo">
            <Name>COMPONENT_TREESHARIFLE_SUPP</Name>
            <Model>treesharifle_supp</Model>
            <LocName>"SUPPRESSOR"</LocName>
            <LocDesc>"SUPPRESSOR"</LocDesc>
            <AttachBone>AAPSupp</AttachBone>
            <WeaponAttachBone>WAPSupp</WeaponAttachBone>
            <AccuracyModifier type="NULL"/>
            <bShownOnWheel value="true"/>
            <CreateObject value="true"/>
            <HudDamage value="-5"/>
            <HudSpeed value="0"/>
            <HudCapacity value="0"/>
            <HudAccuracy value="0"/>
            <HudRange value="-5"/>
            <MuzzleBone>Gun_SuMuzzle</MuzzleBone>
            <FlashFx>muz_assault_rifle</FlashFx>
            <ShouldSilence value="true" />
        </Item>
    </Infos>
    <InfoBlobName/>
</CWeaponComponentInfoBlob>


